# does running tests in order effect the instrumentation testing in junit 4, because some objects are getting nulled

Tags: android, junit4

the stacktrace is showing that the app is trying to invoke a virtual method if i made the tests execute in a specific order.
If I remove the order of execution , those objects are not getting nulled and the running application is not getting effected.

Comment: Proper tests should never assume they will be run in a certain order.

Comment: To elaborate on what @michaelcarrano said, unit tests should never assume that state has been established by other tests. Each test should be capable of running in isolation, and setting up/tearing down any state that it needs to do its work. 

Doing it this way, makes it easy (or at least easier) to debug tests that fail, because you can see all of the setup that was done, and all of the assumptions that the test is making without understanding what might have been done before the test ran.

Comment: It's impossible to understand what your problem is given the amount of detail you provided. Please attach relevant code snippets. And, as mentioned in previous comments, try to remove dependencies between the tests.